# How to extract i18n translation with Symfony 1.4 with catalogues

Tags: php, symfony1, internationalization, symfony-1.4

I would like to be able to get all the translations (translated or not) from a specific catalogue with Symfony 1.4. I use the default message source (XLIFF). An important point is that I need to extract the strings from another application of my project.

Thanks.

Comment: I need to do this within an Action

Comment: Could you clarify your question please? Are you familiar with the i18n:extract task? That's a very good (the best) way to extract all translations from your view files.

Comment: When you set a translation in your code with the helper __(), you can specify a catalogue (third argument), what I need is a class/method to extract only the values that are in a specified catalogue. Actually I can extract them all with the class sfI18nApplicationExtract, but I didn't find the way to get the result by catalogue. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a symfony way to do that, but no problem, the xliff files are simple xmls anyway. Use php's dom methods to get all `trans-unit` tags.